# Can You Use a Lambda In A Class' Initialization List?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11

I am trying to use a C++11 Lambda to initialize a `const` member variable of a class.

A much simplified example:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    const int n_;
    Foo();
};

Foo::Foo()
:   n_( []() -> int { return 42; } )
{
}

int main()
{
    Foo f;
}
```

In MSVC10 this yields:

```
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from '`anonymous-namespace'::<lambda0>' to 'const int'
```

In [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/xmTYR) this yields:

```
prog.cpp: In constructor 'Foo::Foo()':
prog.cpp:9:34: error: invalid conversion from 'int (*)()' to 'int'
```

I'm starting to get the idea that I can't use lambdas in a class' initialization list.

Can I?  If so, what's the proper syntax?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

you are trying to convert from a lambda to int - you should call the lambda instead:

```
Foo::Foo()
:   n_( []() -> int { return 42; }() ) //note the () to call the lambda!
{
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Your variable is declared as `int`.

Do you want to *invoke* the lambda? This should work:

```
n_(([]() -> int { return 42; })())
```

Or did you want a variable of type `std::function<>`?

Comment: +1:  Yes, I am trying to populate `n_` by returning the value from the lambda.

Comment: @John See update. And I actually see how that can be useful with a more complex (multi-statement) lambda.

Comment: Exactly.  In my actual use case, I am storing the size of a read-only file in bytes.

Answer (score 2):

You're creating a lambda, this way as compiler states, you're trying to store the lambda itself in n_.